# Difference between titanium classic and titanium alloy?

Tags: android, titanium-alloy

I am new for titanium. Any one can explain difference between titanium classic and titanium alloy ?

Answer (score 2):

Titanium Alloy basically follows MVC (Model,View and Controller) framework with support of backbone.js and underscore.js where as in Classic structure there is no MVC framework.

In Alloy structure, we can write the code for ui and implementation differently in different files whereas in Classic structure we write code and ui functionality in single app.js file.

Alloy structure contains the folders for Models,Views and Controllers in which we can add our code in that particular files.Whereas there is no folders for Classic structure.

Check this out : [Alloy Concepts](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework)

Also check this [here](http://kinetic-media.com/appcelerator-titanium-creating-a-basic-window-in-classic-code-and-alloy-code/)

Hope this helps.